# How to configure Ninject so that it would inject right instance depending on previously injected instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject, ninject-2

I can't find right words for my question so i will let my code speak instead.

I have Repository:

```
class Repository
{
    public Repository(DbContext ctx)
    {

    }
}
```

then i have this bindings:

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
Bind<DbContext>().To<UserStoreContext>().When...
Bind<DbContext>().To<CentralStoreContext>().When...
```

and then i have class that needs to access both db's

```
class Foo
{
    public Repository(IRepository userRepo, [CentralStoreAttribute]IRepository centralRepo)
    {

    }
}
```

How should i configure two `DbContext` bindings so that repositories with right contexts (based on CentralStoreAttribute) would be injected into Foo constructor?

Comment: I realized that my approach wont work because when i request IRepository in request context, i get same one (first) no matter if I ask for one with different DbContext. So i revert all my code to use Paul Equis suggested way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than relying on attributes in the right places, I usually create several types that are effectively just aliases.  This is useful since with Ninject (and presumably other IoC containers) we're asking for dependencies by their type-name.

So if you need to be able to "request" a user repository vs a central one, I would create types that alias it like this:

```
interface IRepository {  /* methods and properties */ }
interface IUserRepository : IRepository {}
interface ICentralRepository : IRepository {}

class Foo
{
   public Foo(IUserRepository userRepo, ICentralRepository centralRepo)
   {
      // assign to fields
   }
}
```

I prefer this because then Ninject doesn't bleed into my app at all, it's more declarative, and I think it's simpler to remember than any convention based attribute approach like the one you're trying.

Comment: @Paul Equis thats good approach, but still if applied to my sample code, how to inject right `DbContext` ?

Comment: @Paul Equis this is what you sugest if i understood correctly
`Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
Bind<ICentralRepository>().To<Repository>();
Bind<DbContext>().To<UserStoreContext>().When...
Bind<DbContext>().To<CentralStoreContext>().When...`
that still dosent solve problem of injecting right DbContext

Comment: Apply the same approach to the `DbContext`.  Make one called `IUserStoreContext` and one called `ICentralStoreContext` and the repositories request the one they need.

Comment: @Paul Equis and how my repository class then should look? DbContext is not my type, it's framework's.

Comment: Is DbContext `sealed`? If not, forget the interfaces and just inherit from it.  Your repository constructor would look like this: `UserRepository(UserStoreContext context) { /* assign stuff */ }`

Comment: @Paul Equis i don't need 2 implementations of repositories for each context, i need only one, and if possible i don't want to couple it with any custom context derived from DbContext, i want "generic" repository implementation that coupled only with DbContext

Comment: @Paul Equis I was able to use you suggested concept. I created 2 interfaces as you suggested, also added conditions to DbContext bindings like `.When(r => r.ParentRequest != null && r.ParentRequest.Service.Name == typeof(ICentralStoreRepository).Name)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in a proof of concept but eventually went in a different direction.

```
Bind<IRepository>().ToMethod(x =>
{
  var repositoryType = x.Kernel
                .Get<IConfigObject>()
                .SomeStringPropertyDenotingTheRepository;

  switch (repositoryType )
  {
    case "1": return (IRepository)new Repository1();
    default: return (IRepository)new Repository2();
  }
}).InRequestScope();
```

While it worked, I never figured out if it was using my singleton instance of IObjectB or instantiating a new instance - should be pretty easy to figure out though.  I figured it was calling ToMethod every time I used DI on IRepository - again not verified.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `When(Func<IRequest, bool> condition)` overload to check recursivly if `r.Target.IsDefined(typeof(TAttribute), false)` is true for the given request or one of its anchestors `r.ParentRequest`

Comment: this works for constructor injections. But I also have places where i'm getting instance directly from kernel, like `kernel.Get<IRepository>(...)` what should i provide to `Get` method to get `Repository` with `CentralStoreContext` ?

Comment: @qrow: The answer is pretty simple. Do not use Ninject as service locator and you do not have this problem.

Comment: you mean stop getting instances directly from kernel? If so then i can't, i'm using framework that creates my types instead of me, so it needs parameter-less constructor. I don't know any other way then to get instances from kernel in that parameter-less constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
Bind<DbContext>().To<CentralStoreContext>()
    .When( context => context.Target != null 
        && context.Target.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( CentralStoreAttribute ) ) != null );

// make the general binding after the more specific one
Bind<DbContext>().To<UserStoreContext>();
```

Comment: this seems like it wont work? first GetCustomAttributes takes 2 parameters, and returns object[], but event if i change it to `context.Target.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CentralStoreAttribute), false).Any()` it still looks for attribute at target that is DbContext but I specified attribute on IRepository

Comment: your example probably doing same thing as `.WhenTargetHas()` what i need is something like `.WhenParentTargetHas()`

Comment: sorry, I have an extension method that does exactly that, and was typing from memory.  mine looks like: `context.Target.HasAttribute<CentralStoreAttribute>()`